# Comparing two objects - strict weak

Tags: c++

I have a problem comparing objects of the following class: (Only the fields are relevant)

```
class Rule{

private:
    string _src_IP,
        _src_port,
        _dest_IP,
        _dest_port,
        _protocol; };
```

_src_IP and _dst_IP can contain an IP address ("0.0.0.0"-"255.255.255.255")
                      or "any".
_src_Port and _dst_Port can contain a port number ("0" - "65535")
                        or "any".
_protocol can contain "TCP", "UDP", or "any".

The difficulty is creating a comparison (operator< and operator>) which will satisfy the standard mathematical definition of a strict weak ordering.

If someone can think of something, that will be very helpful.

Comment: There are infinite ways to do that, and I don't see any problems. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to use this structure as key in a tree-based associative container (like std::map), and find rules that match a certain specific set of values (using "any" matches if required).

This is not possible, though: A strict weak ordering (the requirement for keys) means that while you don't have to be able to tell for each pair of different values, which one is greater, the *only* allowed deviation is that you may make groups, in which you consider all elements equal. String representations of decimal integers are an example: You "2" and "002" are equal to each other, although they are different strings. If I find another string that equals one string in that same group (like "02", which considered equal to "2"), I can be sure it compares equal to *all* strings in that group.

In your setting, you want to consider 192.168.0.1->8.8.8.8:53/udp to be considered equal to any->8.8.8.8:53/udp, so they have to be in the same group. The same thing is true for 10.0.3.5->8.8.8.8:53/udp, which should also be considered equal to any->8.8.8.8/udp. If it were a strict weak ordering, you would also need to consider 10.0.3.5->8.8.8.8:53/udp equal to 192.168.0.1->8.8.8.8:53/udp, which is something you most likely do not want.

Comment: What do you mean by groups?

Comment: By "group" I mean a couple of the values you want to put a strict weak ordering on. "2", "02" and "002" are in the same group in my example. All objects in a group must be equal to each other (often they are called "equivalent"), and no element in that group must be equal to any element not in that group.

Comment: Ok, so which data structure do you suggest me to use?